# 「RESTを採用していないAPI」とはどういう意味ですか？ 通信プロトコルやリクエスト/レスポンス形式と関係がありますか？

Tags: api

とあるAPIにRESTを採用していない、と書いてあるのですがどういう意味ですか？

> HTTP APIはすべてPOSTで、リクエスト/レスポンスともにJSON形式

[MisskeyはRESTを採用していません。](https://misskey-hub.net/docs/api/)

---

REST
・通信は、HTTPではなくてもよい？
・リクエスト/レスポンスは、JSONではなくてもよい？
・統一インターフェースと書いてありましたが、そもそもAPIで、統一ではないインターフェースがあるのですか？

SOAP
・通信は、HTTPではなくてもよい？
・リクエスト/レスポンスは、XML？

Comment: あなたの言う REST の意味は？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REST API とは、一般的に RESTful な特徴を持つ API を指します。

> RESTを採用していません

とわざわざ言及しているからには、この RESTful な特徴を持たないという事なのでしょう。

---

では、 RESTful な特徴とは何かと言うと、 [RESTful APIとは何なのか - Qiita](https://qiita.com/NagaokaKenichi/items/0647c30ef596cedf4bf2#rest%E3%81%AE%E5%8E%9F%E5%89%87) の説明を借りれば、以下のようなものです。

> - アドレス可能性(Addressability)
>
>   - 提供する情報がURIを通して表現できること。全ての情報はURIで表現される一意なアドレスを持っていること。
> - ステートレス性(Stateless)
>
>   - HTTPをベースにしたステートレスなクライアント/サーバプロトコルであること。セッション等の状態管理はせず、やり取りされる情報はそれ自体で完結して解釈できること。
> - 接続性(Connectability)
>
>   - 情報の内部に、別の情報や(その情報の別の)状態へのリンクを含めることができること。
> - 統一インターフェース(Uniform Interface)
>
>   - 情報の操作(取得、作成、更新、削除)は全てHTTPメソッド(GET、POST、PUT、DELETE)を利用すること。

ここでその [Misskey API](https://misskey-hub.net/docs/api/) とやらを見てみると、

> [APIリファレンス](https://misskey-hub.net/docs/api/endpoints.html)

URI に `create` とか `delete` などが含まれており、 URI がリソース指向になっていない、すなわちアドレス可能性が無いといえそうです。

> ```
> https://{host}/api/miauth/{session}/check
> ```

URL にセッションIDが含まれていて、とてもステートレスとは言い難そうです。

> - HTTP APIはすべてPOSTで

CRUD 操作 (作成、取得、更新、削除) が全て POST メソッドになっていて、統一インターフェースになっていませんね。

---

と RESTful の原則に全く則っていないことがよくわかります。

ただ、それが良い悪いという話ではありません。 念のため。

なお、以下のコメントですが

> REST
> ・通信は、HTTPではなくてもよい？
> ・リクエスト/レスポンスは、JSONではなくてもよい？
> ・統一インターフェースと書いてありましたが、そもそもAPIで、統一ではないインターフェースがあるのですか？

REST は規約ではないので、 RESTful に則れば HTTP でなくとも REST API だと言い張れそうですが、 HTTP 以外は見たことないですね。 SMB あたりなら準拠できそう。

一方、メッセージのフォーマットが JSON でないものは割と一般的で、むしろ登場当初は XML が使われることが多くありました。

統一インターフェースの説明は、上の説明の通りです。

> SOAP
> ・通信は、HTTPではなくてもよい？
> ・リクエスト/レスポンスは、XML？

SOAP はプロトコルとして仕様が決まっており、メッセージのフォーマットは XML が必須です。

アプリケーション層の伝送は、 HTTP の他、 SMTP なども使えるようですが、実用上としてはほぼ HTTP 一択です。

Comment: 私が普段使用しているPHPではほとんどPOSTメソッドしか使用しないのでCRUD 操作も当然POSTメソッドを使用する、と思っていました。ここで言うCRUD 操作とは、HTTPメソッドのことなのですね。また、「URI に create とか delete などが含まれており、 URI がリソース指向になっていない」の意味が分からなかったのですが、検索したら「URI中に操作を表す語彙を使うと一貫した(統一された)インターフェースが保証されない」と書いてありました。ちょっと意味が分からなかったのですが、とにかくそういうものだと理解しました。